# Nesting classes as object and get results

Tags: php

I'm a beginner on OOP but i cant any related answer maybe im not searching the right way, am looking to do the following

```
$country->city()->get_citizens ();
```

The basic idea is based on how laravel is doing its queries like

```
$query->select()->from ()
```

Comment: And? What's your question?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/504/classes-and-objects/2190/method-chaining-in-php#t=201609301818437833939

Comment: @katie very close thanks mate but what if I want to chain classes with a lot of methods?

Comment: @user3049652 - you can chain as many methods as you want as long as each of them has a "return $this" to allow the chaining to continue, the best thing to do is try creating your own with some simple sample, then it will start to make sense...good luck!

Comment: This is called method chaining/fluent api.

Answer (score -1):

`$query->select()` is a function that returns an instance of a object that has the `from()` method

Example: works.

```
class query {
  private $thing;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->thing = new thing();
  }
  public function select() {
    return $this->thing;
  }
}

class thing {
  public function from() {
    echo "Called from";
  }
}


$query = new query();
$query->select()->from();
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{'` and `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)`

Comment: I think its fixed. Like I said its just an example.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I fixed it. The code works on php fiddle.